# Regular expression to match an specific word in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to make a program that should checks if the string that the program is currently looking at, contains the word `ing` in that specific order. I figured out to just split the string with spaces, so each word can be looked at individually. I am stuck on the if condition. The if condition determines if the word has ing in it. For the assignment I can only use one loop and two if statements. I cannot use the string methods tolower or upppercase. Also this what the output needs to look like: (for the output i have a test class that gives me strings to test out)

Words with ing:
Singing Dancing

if I do not find any words what have ing the output should like this
There are no words with ing

Here is my `code` till now:

```
public class EndsWith
{
   public static void endsWithIng (String s)
   {       
      String[] a = s.splits(" ");
      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      {          
         // if()
         System.out.print(a[i] + "");          
      }     
   }
}
```

Comment: I messed up the code when pasting it I am still new to this website so I apologize in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my problem. I forgot to mention that the problem also required a specific print statement. My solution is similar but I made a new string and added any words that I found  with ing to that new string. Also I used a counter to keep track if a word with ing is even found in the first place. If it is not than I printed after the loop no words with ing found.

```
 public class EndsWith
{// start of cLASS
   public static void endsWithIng (String s)
     {// START of method
      String ing="";
      String compare="";
      String [] a = s.split(" ");
       //System.out.println("Words with ing: ");

      int i;
      int count=0;
      for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {//start of for
       

         compare=a[i];
         
         if(compare.matches(".*[iI][nN][gG].*"))
         { //start of if
            
                //System.out.print(compare + " ");
                count++;        
                 ing+=a[i] +" ";
           }
         
                    
      

       }
             if(count==0)
             {
               System.out.println("There are no words with ing");
              }
              else
              {
               System.out.println("Words with ing: ");
               System.out.println(ing);
              }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to split on one (or more) white-space characters. You can also use [`String.endsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-)<sup>1</sup>. Something like,

```
public static void endsWithIng(String s) {
    String[] a = s.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].toLowerCase().endsWith("ing")) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**or** you could use an [enhanced `for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like<sup>2</sup>

```
public static void endsWithIng(String s) {
    String[] a = s.split("\\s+");
    for (String value : a) {          // <-- for each value in array a
        // This checks if the last three characters make the String "ing"
        if ("ing".equalsIgnoreCase(value.substring(value.length() - 3))) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

To use a *regular expression*, beyond [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), you can use [`String.matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) like

```
public static void endsWithIng(String s) {
    String[] a = s.split("\\s+");
    for (String value : a) { // <-- for each value in array a
        // This test ignores case for iI nN gG
        if (value.matches(".*[(i|I)(n|N)(g|G)]$")) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>1<sub>You since added the stipulation that you cannot use `toLowerCase`. Next time, for better help faster, please give **all** the requirements when you ask the question.</sub></sup>

<sup>2<sub>This example uses [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).</sub></sup>

Comment: this is great except for one issue this does not take into account any combination of capital and lower case ing. Also your answer did not address my issue of using regular expressions in a if statment

Comment: @ProgramingMasterJam Added case insensitivity and a regular expression example. You can also compile a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and then use a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: for the homework i cannot use toLowerCase or to highyercase

Comment: @ProgramingMasterJam I *edited* to include two examples that do not use `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase`. Next time, please include **all** of the *requirements* in your question.